# Need help identifying this component recovered from a Fostex X28

Tags: transistors, identification

This has been taken from a Fostex X28 4 track recorder and requires spares. I am not familiar with this component and I am unable to find information online. Does anyone know what it is and if there are any equivalents?

[image: photo 1 of component]

[image: photo 2 of component]

Answer (score 1):

the Japanese standard (JIS) deletes the leading "2S".  so lookup 2SB123

Answer (score 1):

its transistor /voltage regulator that forms part of the motor driver circuit found on the back of the display pcb. a143 transistor can be used - 3rd island did video of it on youtube